# Why does the wavelength in curly hair differ?

Tags: evolution, hair, heat

Different people and animals have different wavelengths in the curls in their hair. I understand what purposes hair serves in protecting the skin from light and bugs. I am wondering about the eventual physiological consequences of curly vs straight hairs.

Do the curls help in cooling, blocking light or catching wind over flat hair? Does the wavelength in curly hair have intrinsic properties that physically would give an animal advantages in climates where straight hair would not?

I will be happy to accept another answer.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/261308/why-does-the-wave-lenght-in-curly-hair-differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hypothesis when the curls are left ungroomed they will form knots. These knots form a barrier that works similar to woven wool. Unlike strait hair the mat of knots (dreadlocks) collect dirt and form denser material that insulates against direct light and mosquitoes better than strait material. The wave length does play a part as well. The smaller the wavelength the tighter the knot. The tightest knots are commonly found in places that have the most sun light per year.

Strait hair tends to keep heat in more and ice builds up less on it.